# replace string with split_part function

Tags: postgresql

I want to replace the first word before delimeter ' ,' with ' 0, the first word ')

```
select replace('tab,graph,map', split_part('tab,graph', ',', 1) like 'tab','0, tab')
```

ERROR:  function replace(unknown, boolean, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select replace('tab,graph,map', split_part('tab,graph', ',',...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` function replaces all occurrences of the string so you have to make sure the string to replace is unique or use something else. However, [`regexp_replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) only replaces the first occurrence by default so you can use that; your question is a little unclear about what the expected output is but maybe this is is what you're looking for:

```
=> select regexp_replace('tab,graph,map', ',', '0,');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 tab0,graph,map
```

Or this one:

```
=> select regexp_replace('tab,graph,map', 'tab,', '0,');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 0,graph,map
```

Or maybe even this:

```
=> select regexp_replace('tab,graph,map', 'tab,', '0,,');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 0,,graph,map
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to cast, since the function expects replace(text, text, text) and does not know how to handle your literal strings calling them unknown...

```
cast('tab,graph,map' AS text)
```

also the 2nd param is a LIKE comparison ? which returns boolean, but the function replace expects it to be the delimiter.

```
CAST(split_part('tab,graph', ',', 1) AS text)
```

finally the last param (same problem as the first)

```
cast('0, tab' AS text)
```

**of course if you really just want to prepend '0, ' to your string, 'tab,graph,map' you could just do that...**

```
SELECT '0, ' || 'tab,graph,map' ;
```

Comment: that is not only to prepend '0, ' but the word tab is not only in the first word ex : tab,map,tab.graph... i want to replace tab in the first word before delimeter with '0,'